# RS232 interface protocol

Tags: serial-port

I'm developing a new board that should connect to other devices like PLC or industrial PC trough rs232.
The remote devices will connect to read and set some parameters (most of them one byte value).

I'm asking if is there any standard protocol to do that or if I can implement something proprietary that customers must follow .

I tought to use AT commands but my device has nothing to do with modems.

Comment: Modern interfaces such as USB, SATA, and HDMI are controlled by organizations that specify/regulate all aspects and might even certify products in order to ensure compatibility and market acceptance. An old interface such as serial ports and RS-232 have no such constraints or oversight committee. You can use any text or binary messaging scheme you can dream up and implement. But if you want a reliable communication channel, then you need to do more than imitate Hayes AT modem commands but probably not go as far as imitate TCP (e.g. there's no message-order problem with point-to-point RS-232).

Comment: It is conceivable that de facto standard protocols may exist depending on the target industry field, equipment type, control details, etc., but your question lacks information to identify them. However, even if such information is available, it will often be command/response via tty console and text I/O.